# Custom notification sound not working after app release

Tags: android, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, notification-channel

I would like to use custom notification sounds.
I have written the code as follows

```
      Future<void> _createNotificationChannel(String id, String name, String description, String sound) async {
        final flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
        var androidNotificationChannel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
          id,
          name,
          description: description,
          sound: sound == "default" ? null : RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound(sound),
          playSound: true,
        );

        await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()?.createNotificationChannel(androidNotificationChannel);
      }

      try {
        _createNotificationChannel("sos", "sos_channel", "緊急通報用", "new_sos_sound");
        _createNotificationChannel("claim", "claim_channel", "クレーム用", "new_claim_sound");
        _createNotificationChannel("default", "default_channel", "通常の通知", "default");
        print('************************* Success created notification channel *****************************');
      } catch (e) {
        print('*************************Error(createNotificationChannel): $e *****************************');
      }
```

```
async function pushToDevice(
  token: string,
  title: string,
  body: string,
  badgeCount: number,
  messageType: string
): Promise<void> {
  const pushMessage = (
    _token: string,
    _title: string,
    _body: string,
    _badgeCount: number,
    _messageType: string
  ): admin.messaging.TokenMessage => {
    return {
      token: _token,
      data: {
        metadata: "someMetadata",
        messageType: _messageType
      },
      notification: {
        title: _title,
        body: _body
      },
      android: {
        priority: "high",
        notification: {
          title: _title,
          body: _body,
          channelId:
            _messageType == "sos"
              ? "sos"
              : _messageType == "claim"
              ? "claim"
              : "default"
        }
      },
    }
  }



  await admin
    .messaging()
    .send(pushMessage(token, title, body, badgeCount, messageType))
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nv0Vb.png)

This works when tested with "flutter run" using a real device, but does not work after the app is released.

When I check from the device settings screen, I was able to confirm that the notificaiton channel was created.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIrMv.jpg)

I can also confirm that custom sounds are set for each channel.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lN58.jpg)

However, I cannot hear the custom sound on the device settings screen.
When I was running with "flutter run", I could hear the custom sound from the device settings screen.

I don't know where the problem is.

Sorry for my poor English.
Thank you in advance for your help.

◎flutter doctor

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.2538], locale ja-JP)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.1.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 4.2)
[√] VS Code (version 1.84.2)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] Network resources
```

I don't know where the problem is.

Comment: Is the device used to test the development environment and the production environment the same device?